# Django form submit error

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm using `kwargs` to populate my djnago form initially,

- Forms.py

  ```
   class myForm(Forms.Form):  
     textbox1 = forms.CharField()  
     dropdown1 = forms.ChoiceField()  


     def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):  
       choices = kwargs.pop('choices')  
       super(myForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)  
       self.fields['dropdown1'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
  ```
- views.py

  ```
  def myjob(req):  
    ch = {("1","A"),("2","B")}  
    if req.method == "POST":  
      frm = myForm(data=req.POST) # throws error saying can't find choices in Forms.py  
    else:  
      frm = myForm(choices=ch) # no problem here
  ```

This code is throwing an error while submitting data as it is trying to call **init** again.
How can I submit correctly?

Comment: This question is not clear. Assuming that `req` is the request, that code does give you the data that has been posted. Please post the actual view, plus the errors that you get.

Comment: Please take a look now, hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems quite clear: the code is expecting a `choices` kwarg, and you're not providing it on POST. You can simply add it:

```
if req.method == "POST":  
    frm = myForm(data=req.POST, choices=ch)
```

Comment: yes, this works but isn't there anything like overloaded init so that I don't have to pass choice? I'm relatively new to django.

Comment: Python doesn't have overloading. You've already redefined init so that it expects choices. But if you didn't pass them, what would be used as the possible choices for `dropdown1`? What would Django use to validate that field if it didn't have any choices assigned?